# Create Instance of Service Reference Proxy Type from Original Type?

Tags: c#, web-services, reflection

Given a Type, say `Apple`, I want to create the equivalent Type that would be created if `Apple` were to be auto-generated as a Service Reference Proxy Type.

So, `Apple` has a Type of `AwesomeWebService.Apple`, but when Studio generates proxy classes for the `AwesomeWebService` service, the Type it creates is something local to the assembly that holds the proxy.

It becomes something like `OtherAssembly.AwesomeWebServiceProxyReference.Apple`

The trick is that I don't know until runtime what proxy Type I want to create (`Apple` or otherwise).  This would be too easy.

I do have an instance of the Service Reference Client, say `OtherAssembly.AwesomeWebServiceProxyReference.AwesomeWebServiceSoapClient`, but I have so far been unable to use this information along with the original Type to get the proxy Type that I am after.  When I try I get an error that the Type could not be found in the assembly.

```
Activator.CreateInstance("OtherAssemblyName", "TypeNameOfOriginalType");
```

where "OtherAssemblyName" is gathered from `proxyClientType.GetType().Assembly.FullName` and "TypeNameOfOriginal" is `originalType.GetType().Name`

```
Activator.CreateInstance("OtherAssembly", "Apple");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Easiest way was just to get the Method I was trying to create the object for (parameter), get the ParameterInfo object, and get the exact Type from that.

```
Type t = proxy.GetType();
MethodInfo m = t.GetMethodInfo("methodName");
ParameterInfo[] mParams = m.GetParameters();
string typeName = mParam.ParameterType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
```